# horizontally centered text in minipage

Tags: minipage

I have a problem with the horizontal align of the text within a minipage environment.

Below is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,answers, addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,lastpage}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{censor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\hyphenpenalty 10000
\usepackage[paperheight=10.5in,paperwidth=8.27in,bindingoffset=0in,left=0.8in,right=1in,
top=1in,bottom=1in,headsep=1.5\baselineskip]{geometry}
\flushbottom
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand\ULthickness{2pt} %%---> For changing thickness of underline
\setlength\ULdepth{1.5ex}%\maxdimen ---> For changing depth of underline
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\headrule
\newcommand{\continuedmessage}{%
\ifcontinuation{\footnotesize Question \ContinuedQuestion\ continues\ldots}{}%
}
\runningheader{\footnotesize Dipartimento di Economia}
{\footnotesize Analisi delle Politiche Pubbliche -- LM56}
{\footnotesize Pagina \thepage\ di \numpages}
\footrule
\footer{\footnotesize}
{}
{\ifincomplete{\footnotesize Question \IncompleteQuestion\ Continua nella pagina successiva}{\iflastpage{\footnotesize \textit{\bfseries Fine domande di esame}}{\footnotesize \textit{\bfseries Continua nella pagina successiva}}}}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}
\renewcommand\thequestion{\arabic{question}}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\thequestion)}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\nopointsinmargin 
\pointpoints{Mark}{Marks}

\marginpointname{\points}
\pointformat{\boldmath\themarginpoints}
\bracketedpoints

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.20\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo} 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.65\textwidth}
{\bfseries Ph.D. in Economics, Management and Statistics}\par
\medskip
{\bfseries University of Catania \& University of Messina}\par
\medskip
\end{minipage}
\medskip
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo-unict} 
\end{minipage}
\par
\vspace{-3ex}
\begin{center}
\textit{\bfseries \LARGE{Microeconomics}}\par
\end{center}
\vspace{-3ex}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
{\bfseries Lecturers:}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  Dr. X\\
  Dr. Y\\
  Dr. Z\\
\bigskip
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\textit{\textbf{Name:}}{\hrulefill}\par
\bigskip
\textit{\textbf{Signature:}} {\hrulefill}\par
\bigskip 
\end{minipage}
\begin{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that I would like to have the text in the red box horizontally centered. Is there any chance I can get this? Thanks in advance

[image]

ADDENDUM

After suggestion made by David, this is what I got. I am not sure whether the text seems to be closer to the logo on the rhs because of an optical effect or it is in fact closer. The picture of the result is below:

[image]

SECOND ADDENDUM

After suggestions by David, I modified my code as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,answers, addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,lastpage}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{censor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\hyphenpenalty 10000
\usepackage[paperheight=10.5in,paperwidth=8.27in,bindingoffset=0in,left=0.8in,right=1in,
top=1in,bottom=1in,headsep=1.5\baselineskip]{geometry}
\flushbottom
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand\ULthickness{2pt} %%---> For changing thickness of underline
\setlength\ULdepth{1.5ex}%\maxdimen ---> For changing depth of underline
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\headrule
\newcommand{\continuedmessage}{%
\ifcontinuation{\footnotesize Question \ContinuedQuestion\ continues\ldots}{}%
}
\runningheader{\footnotesize Dipartimento di Economia}
{\footnotesize Analisi delle Politiche Pubbliche -- LM56}
{\footnotesize Pagina \thepage\ di \numpages}
\footrule
\footer{\footnotesize}
{}
{\ifincomplete{\footnotesize Question \IncompleteQuestion\ Continua nella pagina successiva}{\iflastpage{\footnotesize \textit{\bfseries Fine domande di esame}}{\footnotesize \textit{\bfseries Continua nella pagina successiva}}}}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}
\renewcommand\thequestion{\arabic{question}}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\thequestion)}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\nopointsinmargin 
\pointpoints{Mark}{Marks}

\marginpointname{\points}
\pointformat{\boldmath\themarginpoints}
\bracketedpoints

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.17\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo}
\end{flushleft} 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.66\textwidth}\centering
{\bfseries Ph.D. in Economics, Management and Statistics}\par
\medskip
{\bfseries University of Catania \& University of Messina}\par
\medskip
\end{minipage}
\medskip
\begin{minipage}{.17\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo-unict}
\end{flushright} 
\end{minipage}
\par
\vspace{-3ex}
\begin{center}
\textit{\bfseries \LARGE{Microeconomics}}\par
\end{center}
\vspace{-3ex}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
{\bfseries Lecturers:}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  Dr. X\\
  Dr. Y\\
  Dr. Z\\
\bigskip
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\textit{\textbf{Name:}}{\hrulefill}\par
\bigskip
\textit{\textbf{Signature:}} {\hrulefill}\par
\bigskip 
\end{minipage}
\begin{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It works fine now. The result is below:

[image]

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[c]{.65\textwidth}\centering` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Thanks. It seems to work, however I notice that if I do as you suggested, the text seems to be closer to the logo on the rhs rather than being equally spaced between the two logos. Do you have any idea on how I can fix this (new) problem?

Comment: It will be exactly centred according to the font metrics (so not taking into account any white space within the letter shapes are you sure it's not just an optical effect from the large left edge of `P`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not sure honestly. Visually, it seems to be closer to the logo on the rhs. I am editing my original question to post the picture.

Comment: oh well each image is flush left in a box of width .2\textwidth so both too far left you want to centre them or make the fist flush left and the second flush right

Comment: also you must get warnings about that box you have two minipages of .2\textwidth  with images a minpage of .65\textwidth with text and a word space between each of the boxes so you are fitting 1.05\textwidth+ 2 word spaces into a line.  You should remove the spaces and make it add up to 1

Comment: Perhaps you could use a `tabular` environment inside a `center` environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Thanks a lot. It works fine using flushleft and flushright for the first and the second logo respectively!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @samcarter. As you may notice from my answers above, the suggestion by David Carlisle worked. So I do not think I should vote for the answer below.

Comment: @Dario Then please either ask David Carlisle to convert his comment into an answer or write one yourself so that other people will know this questions is answered and future user can be guided by the green accepted mark to the answer which helped you most.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to guess dimensions, leave the computations to TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  paperheight=10.5in,
  paperwidth=8.27in,
  bindingoffset=0in,
  left=0.8in,
  right=1in,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
  headsep=1.5\baselineskip,
  showframe,% just for the example
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx,varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-1x1}
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
\centering\bfseries
Ph.D. in Economics, Management and Statistics\\
University of Catania \& University of Messina
\end{varwidth}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-1x1}
\end{tabular}%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]